# dynamic site in file_get_contents

Tags: php, captcha

problem , Crossing the CAPTCHA in dynamic site .. :(
problem link action form in https://edu.uast.ac.ir ..
sorry My English is not good.

please test my code :

my source code :

a.php

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("https://edu.uast.ac.ir");
?>
```

b.php

```
<?php
$a  =  $_POST["captcha_first_page"];

$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'captcha_first_page' => $a
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);    
$result = file_get_contents('https://edu.uast.ac.ir/user/user_manage/userLogin/', false, $context);
echo $result;
?>
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the form action, too, cause if not the submitted form want posted to your b.php.

**captcha-a.php**

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents("https://edu.uast.ac.ir");
$content = str_replace('https://edu.uast.ac.ir/user/user_manage/userLogin/','captcha-b.php', $content);
echo $content;
```

**captcha-b.php**

```
<?php
function redirect_post($url, array $data, array $headers = null) {
    $params = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );

    // replace
    $headers['Host'] = "edu.uast.ac.ir";
    $headers['Origin'] = "https://edu.uast.ac.ir";
    $headers['Referer'] = "https://edu.uast.ac.ir";

    if (!is_null($headers)) {
        $params['http']['header'] = '';
        foreach ($headers as $k => $v) {
            $params['http']['header'] .= "$k: $v\n";
        }
    }
    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
    $fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
    if ($fp) {
        return stream_get_contents($fp);
    } else {
        // Error
        throw new Exception("Error loading '$url', $php_errormsg");
    }
}

setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF8");
echo redirect_post("https://edu.uast.ac.ir/user/user_manage/userLogin/" ,$_POST, getallheaders());
```

This should be a good starting point. Don't know if it works cause I can't really speak arabian.

Comment: @j14 i will look at it .. is that the content of captcha-b.php?

Comment: yes ..
Should be displayed:
[link] https://edu.uast.ac.ir/user/user_manage/userLogin

But it was the image that comes...
I'm in a hurry, my friend.Please test your code .. tnx

Comment: @j14 coud I use cURL, too?

Comment: sry @j14 ok i will look at it in the afternoon